# matching Inequalities

Tags: pattern-matching, inequalities

Consider the following list

```
list={0 < x < 1/12, 0 < x < 1/4}
```

I wish to find the intersection of the two ranges of `x` and check if the result is an element of the above list, i.e.

```
In:=Simplify[And @@ list]
out:=0<x<1/12
```

Now I want to check if the above range of `x` belongs to the `list`.

```
in:=MemberQ[list, Simplify[And @@ list]]
out:= False
```

But It is clear that such a range is an element of `list`. This is not giving the expected result because the Heads are not matching.

```
in:=FullForm[Simplify[And @@ list]]
out:=Inequality[0,Less,x,Less,Rational[1,12]]
```

Whereas,

```
in:=FullForm[0 < x < 1/12]
out:=Less[0,x,Rational[1,12]]
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: This is weird. I didn't know it converted to `Inequality`. A possible workaround is to construct intervals like `intervals = Interval[{First[#], Last[#]}] & /@ list;` then do `result = IntervalIntersection @@ intervals` and `MemberQ[intervals, result]` is true. But this will not work well for arbitrary inequalities, only these two sided ones.

Comment: Forcing it to expand the inequalities into logical expressions with && seems to work around it too ```MemberQ[Reduce`InequalityExpand /@ list, Reduce`InequalityExpand[Simplify[And @@ list2]]]```

Comment: Yes. After using `LogicalExpand`, it is working

Answer (score 1):

Your intent is interval arithmetics. Mathematica offers specialized built-ins to deal with intervals.

[`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html)

```
IntervalUnion[Interval[{0, 1/12}], Interval[{0, 1/4}]]

Interval[{0, 1/4}]

IntervalIntersection[Interval[{0, 1/12}], Interval[{0, 1/4}]]

Interval[{0, 1/12}]

FullForm@IntervalIntersection[Interval[{0, 1/12}], Interval[{0, 1/4}]]

Interval[List,[0,Rational[1,12]]]
```

This is some a tautology and the check corresponding Your MemberQ input is redundant.

On the other hand there is the built-in [`IntervalMemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html):

```
IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, 1/12}], Interval[{0, 1/15}]]

True
```

To more directly:

```
Equal[Inequality[0, Less, x, Less, Rational[1, 12]], 
 Less[0, x, Rational[1, 12]]]

(0 < x < 1/12) == (0 < x < 1/12)
```

The output is not True and

Expand[%]

does not alter any.

But

Equivalent@Equal[Inequality[0, Less, x, Less, Rational[1, 12]],
Less[0, x, Rational[1, 12]]]

True

[`Equivalent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equivalent.html) represents the logical equivalence of both representation.

```
Equivalent[%741] // TautologyQ

True

TautologyQ@Equal[Inequality[0, Less, x, Less, Rational[1, 12]], 
     Less[0, x, Rational[1, 12]]]

False
```

It is in the terms of Mathematica not a direct tautology, but is set with Equal.

```
NumberLinePlot[{Interval[{0, 1/4}], Interval[{0, 1/12}]}]
```

[image: NumberLinePlot]

This does not work with the Inequality.

```
NumberLinePlot[Simplify[And @@ list], {x, 0, .1}]
```

[image: NumberLinePlot]

This brings up the real differences between both representation and how there are meant to be made equal in Mathematica.

And it visualizes the main drawback. The interval in Mathematica is closed, the inequalities are strict and therefore open.

The very most suitable answer is use Reduce:

```
Reduce[list, x]
```

0 < x < 1/12

```
Reduce[Inequality[0, Less, x, Less, Rational[1, 12]], x]
```

0 < x < 1/12

FullForm of both is the very same.

```
FullForm@Reduce[Inequality[0, Less, x, Less, Rational[1, 12]], x]
```

Inequality[0,Less,x,Less,Rational[1,12]]

FullForm@Reduce[list, x]
Inequality[0,Less,x,Less,Rational[1,12]]

```
FullForm@Reduce[Inequality[0, Less, x, Less, Rational[1, 12]], x]==FullForm@Reduce[list, x]
```

True

Comment: `Equivalent@Equal[Inequality[0, Less, x, Less, Rational[1, 12]], Less[0, x, Rational[1, 12]]]` This isn't doing what you think. Try `Equivalent@Equal[1, 0]` for example. It returns `True`.